# Box topology is finer than the uniform topology on $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}$

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification, metric-spaces, product-space

[This time](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1865699/uniform-topology-is-finer-than-the-product-topology-on-mathbbr-mathbbn/1865725#1865725), I wish to show that the **box topology is finer than the uniform topology** on countable Cartesian products on $\mathbb{R}$ denoted $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}$

However, the problem here is that the box topology is not metrizable, so we cannot compare metric balls...

All is not lost, because we know what those basic open sets are

- The base on the **b**ox topology on $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}$ is:

$$B_b = \Bigg\{\prod_{n \in \mathbb{N}} U_n: U_n \subset \mathbb{R} \text{ is open }\Bigg\}$$

- The base on the **u**niform topology on $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}$ :

$$B_u =  \Bigg\{B_\epsilon^u(x):x \in \mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N},  \epsilon > 0  \Bigg\}$$

where $$B_\epsilon^u(x) = \{y \in \mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}|d_u(x,y)<\epsilon\} = \{y \in \mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}|  \sup_{n\in \mathbb{N}}(\min\{1, |x_n-y_n|\})< \epsilon\}$$

$$d_u(x,y) = \sup_{n\in \mathbb{N}}(\min\{1, |x_n-y_n|\})$$

> We wish to show that $\mathcal{T}_u \subseteq \mathcal{T}_b
>  \Leftrightarrow B_b \subseteq B_u$

**Proof attempt:**

> - We want to take $U \in B_b$ and show that $U \in B_u$.
> - Let $U \in B_b$, then $U = \prod_{n \in \mathbb{N}} U_n$, for some    countable collection of $\{U_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$
>        (err....we have  a basic open set defined in term of components, but    the basic open sets in uniform topology is not)
> - Then for each $x \in U$, $\exists \epsilon_x > 0$, such that    $B_{\epsilon_x}^u(x) \subset U$.
> - Claim: $\bigcup_{x \in U} B_{\epsilon_x}^u(x) \in B_u$
> - Then $U \subset \bigcup_{x \in U} B_{\epsilon_x}^u(x) \in B_u$

I am not confident that this proof works, because it seems we can also pick any ball in the uniform topology and find a collection of $\{U_n\}$ such that their union contains the ball...How do I fix this proof. Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Uniform topology is finer than the product topology on $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1865699/uniform-topology-is-finer-than-the-product-topology-on-mathbbr-mathbbn)

Comment: @Gianluca Pretty sure not a duplicate given I wrote the other one.

Comment: I'm Sorry! I read wrong!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You appear to be trying to prove the wrong thing. To show that the box topology is at least as fine as the uniform topology, you need to show that $\mathscr{T}_u\subseteq\mathscr{T}_b$, and if you want to show that it’s strictly finer, you have to show further that $\mathscr{T}_b\setminus\mathscr{T}_u\ne\varnothing$.

Let $U\in\mathscr{T}_u$; if $U=\varnothing$, then certainly $U\in\mathscr{T}_b$, so assume that $U\ne\varnothing$, and let $x\in U$; there is an $\epsilon(x)\in(0,1)$ such that $B_{2\epsilon(x)}^u(x)\subseteq U$. Let

$$V_x=\big(x-\epsilon(x),x+\epsilon(x)\big)^{\Bbb N}\;;$$

clearly $V_x\in\mathscr{T}_b$, and $d_u(x,y)\le\epsilon<2\epsilon$ for each $y\in V_x$, so $x\in V_x\subseteq U$. Thus,

$$U=\bigcup_{x\in U}V_x\in\mathscr{T}_b\;,$$

and $\mathscr{T}_u\subseteq\mathscr{T}_b$.

To show that $\mathscr{T}_b\setminus\mathscr{T}_u\ne\varnothing$, let

$$\begin{align*}
U&=\prod_{n\in\Bbb N}\left(-\frac1{n+1},\frac1{n+1}\right)\\
&=(-1,1)\times\left(-\frac12,\frac12\right)\times\left(-\frac13,\frac13\right)\times\ldots\;;
\end{align*}$$

I’ll leave it to you to verify that $U\notin\mathscr{T}_u$.

Comment: How can I find an open topology in the uniform topology that is not open in the topology product?

Answer (score 0):

My verification for the last comment from Brian M. Scott.

Will this work?

There does not exist an $\epsilon$ small enough such that the $B_{\bar{\rho}}(x_n,\epsilon)$ as $n \to \infty$ is a superset of $(\frac{-1}{n+1}, \frac{1}{n+1})$ as $n \to \infty.$

Comment: This is not an answer to the original question of "How do I fix the 'proof' described above?".  If you think Scott's answer is unclear, consider posting a comment on it; you'll be able to do that once you have enough reputation.  To ask a new question, use the "Ask a Question" button.  (We accept questions asking for clarification on other answers.)