# Is $\mathbb{PR}^{\mathbb{N}}$ compact? (projectivized space of real sequences)

Tags: general-topology

Consider the space $\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}}$ of all real seqences with the product topology (which in this case equals the compact-open topology on $\mathcal{C}(\mathbb{N},\mathbb{R})$, where $\mathbb{N}$ has the discrete topology and $\mathbb{R}$ the usual one, right?). $(\mathbb{R}\setminus \{0\}, \times)$ acts on it by multiplication. Consider the orbit space, i.e. the quotient of the action, $\mathbb{PR}^{\mathbb{N}}$.

Is it compact?

My question comes from considering actions of a countable group on a metric space—these give pseudometrics on the group—and the space of all of these is compact. The proof of this fact could be made nicer if it were true that $\mathbb{PR}^{\mathbb{N}}$ is compact.

Answer (score 1):

$P\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}}$ is compact, consider $u_n=[0,..,1,0..]$, $1$ at the $n$-place, you can extract $u_{n_q}$ which converges towards $u=[u_0,....,u_n,..]$. There exists $n_0$ such that $u_{n_0}\neq 0$ and $u\in U_{n_0}=\{[x_0,..,x_n,..]:x_{n_0}\neq 0\}$, which is open, this implies there exists $N$ such that $n_q>N$ implies that $u_{n_q}\in U_{n_0}$ contradiction since if $n_q>max(n_0,N)$ the $n_0$ component of $u_{n_q}$ is zero.

Comment: I believe that there are points in my $P\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}$ that don't come from your map $p:S^\mathbb{N} \to P\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}$, for example $u = (1,1,1,\ldots)$.

The space $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}$ contains *all* real sequences, not just the ones of finite Euclidean norm.

I have no idea whether one can put a metric on the product space $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}$, but I doubt it.

Comment: Okay, it seems to be metrizable: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1865699/uniform-topology-is-finer-than-the-product-topology-on-mathbbr-mathbbn